# Gyro not working in Cocos2D enviroment

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, gyroscope

I've got a really strange problem. I have an AR app built on the cocos2D library. Recently when I first fire up xcode for the day, the gyro is not working i.e. the yaw and roll is being measured as 0 no matter how the device is oriented. It SHOULD be working based on the check I am performing in the code:

```
    // Initialize Gyro
    self.motionManager = [[[CMMotionManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = (1.0/60.0);
    if (motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"motion available");
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical];
    }
```

I've fixed this issue the past few days by commenting out some lines of stuff I am no longer using or changing something related to sprite animation on screen. The bizarre thing is I'll get it working fine for the rest of my coding session, close xcode, and the next day when I open up xcode and my project again, the gyro is once again broken.

Does anyone with more experience with cocos2d or the gyro know what could possibly be causing this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I commented out the line

```
[mySprite runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:refreshRate position:ccp(newX, newY)]];
```

and ran the app and the gyro worked again. What's strange though is when I uncommented that same line and ran the app again, the gyro still worked. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch … is `motionManager` a retaining property?

Because if not, motionManager will be autoreleased:

```
self.motionManager = [[[CMMotionManager alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Yea it was being retained but I ended up changing that to a class object rather than a property anyway (like Apple's pARk sample project). This is driving me nuts. It just happened again after quitting xcode.